# OnFormSubmit() not firing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to solve the following case: I have a template that is copied by users and linked to a Google Form. Also, I have a script that does some configuration to the Form Responses tab for its further usage. It works perfectly in the template, however, the installable `onFormSubmit()` trigger is not copied together with the template. To solve this I added `onOpen()` trigger that installs the `onFormSubmit()` which was confirmed to work.

The issue I am facing is that while `onFormSubmit()` is successfully installed in the template copy, it still does not fire automatically. I assume that this is related to some permissions issue. Is there any way to rewrite the script to avoid additional authorization?

```
   function onOpen(e) {
 addFormSubmissionListener();
  //// other init...
}

function addFormSubmissionListener() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit")
     .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
     .onFormSubmit()
     .create();
}

function onFormSubmit(e) {
   var range = e.range
   var sheet = range.getSheet();
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   if(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Responses') == null) {
   sheet.setName('Responses');
   sheet.insertColumnsAfter (7,10)
   spreadsheet.getRange('Tech!A:J').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('Responses!H:O'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  sheet.hideColumns(16, 2)
  var curr_sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Jira import')
  updateFormulasTwoRows(curr_sheet);
   }
  
}
```

Comment: 2 questions: 1) can you see the `onFormSubmit` trigger created in the copies? you can see that if you go to the current projects trigger of the copies. 2) you want to attach the main form to the copy spreadsheets as well? or create different forms per spreadsheet?

Comment: 1) yes, the trigger is present in the copies; 2) different forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*If you create a new project you will always have to authorise it, there isn't really a way of getting around this.*