# Installable Trigger not being installed in published Google Forms Editor Add-On

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms, add-on

I have developed a simple Google Forms editor add-on that POSTS a Google Form response to a web service that I've created elsewhere. Here is the code for that below:

```js
function onInstall(e) {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onSubmit").forForm(FormApp.getActiveForm()).onFormSubmit().create();
  onOpen(e);
}

function onSubmit(e) {
  const items = [];
  for (const res of e.response.getItemResponses()) {
    const item = res.getItem();
    items.push({ "title": item.getTitle(), "response": res.getResponse(), "desc": item.getHelpText() });
  }
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://my-web-service.app/gform", {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify({
      "form_title": e.source.getTitle(),
      "form_id": e.source.getId(),
      "response_id": e.response.getId(),
      "items": items,
      "timestamp": e.response.getTimestamp(),
    }),
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
  });
  console.log(`Response Code: ${response.getResponseCode()}`);
}
```

### The Problem

Ideally, when the user installs my add-on, the simple trigger: `onInstall(e) {}` should fire and create my installable trigger. But that isn't happening. The trigger won't install or fire when another user installs my add-on from the Google Workspace Marketplace. Why is that?

I've seen the below previous questions on Stack Overflow:

- [How to correctly implement installable trigger.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70340731/correct-way-to-implement-installable-triggers-in-google-addon-google-app-script)
- [`onFormSubmit()` trigger not firing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66318584/onformsubmit-not-firing)

But these don't really answer my question since they mainly have to do with Google Sheets. My add-on is a Google Forms editor add-on.

Comment: Can you share how your users access the Google Form you created with the add-on?

Answer (score 1):

*It's expected that `The trigger won't install or fire when another user installs my add-on from the Google Workspace Marketplace` because the documentation of [onInstall(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#oninstalle) states that:*

> The `onInstall(e)` trigger runs automatically when a user installs an [Editor Add-on](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/types#editor_add-ons) from within Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, or Forms. The trigger won't run when a user installs the add-on from the ***Google Workspace Marketplace*** website.

Here is the link to that documentation:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#oninstalle

Instead, you can try things like [Universal actions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/universal-actions) to run a function, like in the question [Installable Triggers for workspace Addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75433167).